# Blade templating no error message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a blade template with some PHP logics that look like this:

```
<?php
    $prevCatCode = null;
    $catStyleCode = null;
    $isSameCatCode = false;
?>

<h2>Products</h2>
<table class="productsTable" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($draftOrderProducts as $key => $draftOrderProduct)
        <?php 
            $catStyleCode = $draftOrderProduct['cat_style_code'];
            if ($prevCatCode !== null && $prevCatCode == $catStyleCode) {
                $isSameCatCode = true;
            } else {
                $isSameCatCode = false;
            }
            $prevCatCode = $catStyleCode;

            if (!$isSameCatCode || $key == 0) { ?>
                <tr><td colspan="4"><b>{{ $catStyleCode }}</b>  (Retail Price: {{ $draftOrderProduct['retail_price'] }})</td></tr>;
            <?php } ?>

            <tr>
                <td>{{ $draftOrderProduct['code'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $draftOrderProduct['products_quantity'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ money_format("%(#10n", $draftOrderProduct['products_price']) }} (Retail: {{money_format("%(#10n", $draftOrderProduct['retail_price'])}})</td>
                <td>{{ money_format("%(#10n", $draftOrderProduct['final_price']) }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

I am wondering if I am using the PHP tags correctly within this blade file. Any idea what's wrong there?

`$data` is passed to the template and has the data such as `$data['draftOrderProducts'] = $draftOrderProducts;`

Comment: Where is `$draftOrderProducts` defined? Actually looking at this again that foreach isn't in the PHP.

Comment: I pass in `$data` to the template. $data['draftOrderProducts'] = $draftOrderProducts;

Comment: you have a totally chaos in this view. I'm strongly recommending to move all logic outside blade files and use only blade constructions like ``@foreach``, ``@if``, ``@else`` etc. here.

Comment: I will definitely look into that. However can you notice if anything is wrong with the code here ?